# Passing the user id as parameter

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am trying to pass the id of the user who is logged in as a parameter to the index.

```
 <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/todo/index/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
```

here i want to add the user id who is logged in:

what i have tried to fail:

```
 <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;?>/todo/index/. Yii::$app->user->identity->username ."><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Did you try use this Yii::app()->user->getId();  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/todo/index/'.Yii::$app->user->identity->username;?>">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?= Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">Home', Url::to(['todo/index', 'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id]), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
```

Comment: why you want to use normal way?

Comment: because the designers may not understant if they need to edit any.

Comment: @micky you have Yii's function `Html::a()` to create anchor tags. Try using that. And you should teach the designers how to edit it. :-)

Comment: @SherinJose. Right way.

Comment: @InsaneSkull that too giving error if user is not logged in and if i click home.

Comment: @micky you have to check for logged in user then make link click-able. It's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is great but you should use:

```
<a href="<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(array("todo/index", "uname" => Yii::$app->user->identity->username)); ?>">
```

It is not a good practice too write the SEF url directly. You should format it using rules.